# Configuring Traefik on Windows and http2 support

Tags: windows, http2, traefik

I started experimenting with Traefik on Windows 10 and I need assistance with some very basic steps. Two are my main stumbling blocks: configuring Traefik natively on Windows 10 and http2 support.

### 1) Native Traefik on Windows

Following the instructions at  https://docs.traefik.io/ I successfully managed to install the docker image of Traefik and see the dashboard on localhost:8080
However, when I try to start Traefik natively as "traefik -c traefik.toml" Traefik seems to "hang" no matter what I put in traefik.toml.
Can anybody show me a minimal Windows 10 configuration (.toml) to achieve what I achieve using the Docker version of Traefik?

### 2) HTTP2 support

Following the test shown at https://docs.traefik.io/#test-it, I execute this on the command line:
 curl  -v --http2  -H Host:whoami.docker.localhost http://127.0.0.1
but on the output I see:
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 327
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Date: Wed, 05 Jul 2017 18:51:00 GMT

Does it mean that the response back is http 1.1 ?

Any help is much appreciated.